# Vim: Custom mapping for surround plugin to surround visual selection?

Tags: vim, vim-plugin, dotfiles

I intend to `surround` my **visual selection**, same as **sublime** and other editors.

Since I already have `surround` plugin installed, therefore `viwS"` does surrounds the selected word with `"` and similarly for `'`, etc

Therefore following is my attempt :

```
vnoremap ' S'
vnoremap " S"
vnoremap [ S[
vnoremap { S{
vnoremap ( S(
```

But mysteriously it deletes the entire line and inserts the `quote` when I try using them.

Where am I going wrong ? How to correct it ?

Comment: `S` will clear the whole line and enter insert mode

Comment: But it works when I use `viwS"`. How can I fix it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `*noremap` wrong:

When you use `*noremap`, you ask Vim to use *the original meaning of `S`.*

When you use `*map`, you ask Vim to use *whatever is the current meaning of `S`.*

`vnoremap` is OK if the commands executed by your mapping are supposed to be native commands but you are using a command that is already remapped by a plugin. You should use `*map`, instead.

Additionally, `vmap` covers *visual* and *select* mode: you should probably be more precise in your mappings.

So…

```
xmap ' S'
xmap " S"
xmap [ S[
xmap { S{
xmap ( S(
```

(edit)

Your problem with `<C-c>` is the exact reverse: you are using `vmap` so you are telling Vim to use **whatever `"` currently does**. Because…

1. you have mapped `"` to do `S"`,
2. you use `"` in the RHS of your `<C-c>` mapping,
3. and you use `vmap` for it…

pressing `<C-c>` does `S"+ygv` which is not what you want. The rules above are simple: follow them and all will be good. Here they are again, with a slightly different wording:

- Use `*noremap` when you want to use commands with their default meaning.
- Use `*map` when you want to use commands with their remapped meaning.

Comment: 1 problem, now somehome `<c-c>` is triggering `S"` in visual mode. What happened ?

Comment: It doesn't, here. Maybe a stray mapping?

Comment: This is my `<c-c>` mapping `vmap <c-c> "+ygv`

Comment: Yeah, the problem is obvious if you pay attention to what I wrote. See my edit.

Comment: You are right. I was confusing somethings. Reason is obvious - may be I need some sleep. Thanks man !